# Define python ctypes structure with unknown field type

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I've got a dll which defines a structure. Within this structure is a field that has the type `CRITICAL_SECTION`, as included from `windows.h`. How can I define a ctypes structure in python to reference this type? Since `CRITICAL_SECTION` is itself a struct (with references to other structs in its own definition), do I really have to define the python ctype equivalents such that I have a python `CRITICAL_SECTION` that I can reference? Is there a better way?

**Example C program:**

```
...
typedef struct some_struct {
    ...
    CRITICAL_SECTION field1;
} SOME_STRUCT;
...
```

**Example Python program:**

```
...
class SOME_STRUCT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [... ('field1', CRITICAL_SECTION)]
```

How do I make ctypes recognize what `CRITICAL_SECTION` is without going down the rabbit hole of defining everything down to primitive types that ctypes recognizes?

Comment: Untested, but for the purposes of Python, defining it as `c_ubyte * x` where x is `sizeof(CRITICAL_SECTION)` might be sufficient.  As long as your final structure is the right size, you can just treat it as an opaque array of bytes.

Comment: so what is the `sizeof(CRITICAL_SECTION)` anyway :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ask your C compiler :^)  On mine it was 40 bytes, but it would vary.  I came up with a hopefully better answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to get the top-level structure size right.  `InitializeCriticalSection` should handle setting the structure up.

Looking into the Windows headers, this should work on 32- and 64-bit systems:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes as w

# Set to an unsigned int type that is 32- or 64-bit depending on OS architecture.
# I didn't see a wintype that worked.
ULONG_PTR = c_size_t

class CRITICAL_SECTION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('DebugInfo',w.LPVOID),
                ('LockCount',w.LONG),
                ('RecursionCount',w.LONG),
                ('OwningThread',w.HANDLE),
                ('LockSemaphore',w.HANDLE),
                ('SpinCount',ULONG_PTR)]

k32 = WinDLL('kernel32')
InitializeCriticalSection = k32.InitializeCriticalSection
InitializeCriticalSection.argtypes = POINTER(CRITICAL_SECTION),
InitializeCriticalSection.restype = None

s = CRITICAL_SECTION()
InitializeCriticalSection(byref(s))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This appears to be working for me but I still need time to really test it out. I'll come back and accept which I know it works 100% with my particular application.